# "Quando" e o subjuntivo

Tags: modo-subjuntivo

Eu gostaria de entender melhor quando não é preciso o uso do futuro do subjuntivo com a palavra *quando*.

Como interrogativo não é usado:

> Quando vens?

No passado não é usado:

> Quando vieste para cá, ela chorava.

Pela ótima explicação [deste](http://radames.manosso.nom.br/linguagem/gramatica/morfologia/usos-do-verbo-subjuntivo-futuro/) site, *usa-se o subjuntivo futuro para declarar ações que precisam ocorrer no futuro para que outra ação se efetive*. Por exemplo:

> Quando vieres para cá, explico-te tudo.

O subjuntivo exprime **incerteza**, mas se eu tivesse certeza de que a segunda pessoa viria, seria possível escrever a frase embaixo?

> Quando vens para cá, explico-te tudo.

Outro caso, se a *quando* quer dizer *cada vez que*, imagino que também não se use o subjuntivo:

> Quando o Fulano vai à escola, ele sempre carrega todos os livros.

Isto é correto?

Comment: Para mim, "quando vieres" não exprime incerteza, exprime condicionalidade. Para haver incerteza, precisaria de um se: "se tu vieres".